# Как поместить текст чуть выше возле фотографии

Tags: html, css

Как поместить текст чуть выше, как показано на втором примере? Только учу HTML, весь интернет облазил. Стоит ли прибегать к использованию таблиц?

```css
.class2{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #262425;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px 20px 1px 10px;
    margin: 110px 35px 1px 35px;
}
#n3{
    float: left; /* Обтекание картинки текстом */
}
#n4{
    font-family: arial black;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 10px; /* Отступ от левого края */
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="class2"><img id="n3" src="oblogka2.jpeg" wight="-80" height="220" alt="oblogka2"><p id="n4">Metro 4</p></div>
```

[image: примеры]

Comment: Обнулите margin, в частности margin-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.class2 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #262425;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 20px 1px 10px;
  margin: 110px 35px 1px 35px;
}

#n3 {
  float: left;
}

#n4 {
  font-family: arial black;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="class2">
  <img id="n3" src="oblogka2.jpeg" wight="-80" height="220" alt="oblogka2">
  <p id="n4">Metro 4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте свойство `margin-top` в элементе `#n4`. Попробуйте поставить `margin-top: 0`

Comment: Тот отступ будет касаться родительского блока, а не текста.

Comment: @entithat, изменил, сразу не заметил